# Computing $\liminf A_{n}$ and $\limsup A_{n}$ for a given sequences of sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology, measure-theory

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let

$$A_{2n-1}=\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \: | \: y\geq 0, x\geq 1 +\frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace$$

and

$$A_{2n}=\left\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \: | \: x \geq 0, 0 \leq y \leq 
 \frac{1}{n} \right\rbrace$$

Calculate  $\liminf A_{n}$ and $\limsup A_{n}$. I don't know how to calculate the mentioned limits manually but my intuition says this sequence converges and it converges to

$$A= \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \: | \: x \geq 1, y=0\rbrace.$$ So if this is true then

$$\liminf A_{n}=A=\limsup A_{n}?$$

I need help with the technicalities of the proof as I've never have worked with limits of sequences involving sets. Thanks!

Comment: Each $A_n$ is a set. What do you mean by $liminf A_n$ and $limsup A_n$?

Comment: @freakish liminf is the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$...limsup is the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

Comment: @freakish...it is proved easily that: a point belongs to liminf if  and only if exists $N$ such that $x \in A_k \forall k \geq N$....x belongs to limsup if and only if x belongs to infinitely many $A_k$'s

Comment: My intuition is right claiming that liminf=A=limsup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marios Gretsas indicated in a comment, $\liminf$ is the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$, 
and $\limsup$ is the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$. 
In other words, $x$ belongs to $\limsup$ if $x$ belongs to infinitely 
many $A_k$, and $x$ belongs to $\liminf$ if $x$ belongs to all but finitely 
many $A_k$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

For the sets in the question we do not have that $\limsup=\liminf$.

It is not clear how you have used your intuition to come up with the result you state in the question. Perhaps you could have provided more details.

$\limsup$ might be easier to consider first. From the definition of $A_{2n-1}$ 
it is easily seen that $\limsup A_n\supseteq O:=\{(x,y)|y\ge0,x>1\}$. In fact, 
$\limsup A_{2n-1}=O$ since every point $x$ in $O$ belongs to all but finitely many 
$A_{2n-1}$ (and only points $x$ in $O$ have this property). Since $A_{2n-1}$ is 
an increasing sequence (in particular monotone), we have moreover that 
$\limsup A_{2n-1}=\liminf A_{2n-1}=\lim A_{2n-1}=O$. For an increasing sequence of sets we always have $\limsup =\liminf=\lim=$ the union of the sets, so 
$\lim A_{2n-1}=\cup_n A_{2n-1}=O$ (explaining why $O$ looks the way it does, as defined earlier).

Similarly, $A_{2n}$ is a decreasing sequence and 
$\limsup A_{2n}=\liminf A_{2n}=\lim A_{2n}=\cap_n A_{2n}=E:=\{(x,y)|x\ge0,y=0\}$. 
This is the positive part of the $x$-axis, including the origin.

It follows that $\limsup A_n=O\cup E$.

On the other hand, $\liminf A_n=O\cap E=\{(x,y)|x>1,y=0\}$.

Comment: Thanks so much! But is not clear why $lim inf A_{n}= O \cap E$?? $A_{n}= A_{2n-1} \cup A_{2n}$ but is not always true that $lim inf (A_{n} \cup A_{2n-1})= lim inf(A_{2n}) \cap lim A_{2n-1}$ :S @mirko